# On the ratio test for power series; Hunter

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, power-series

This is a small detail, but I'm stuck nevertheless. In these [lecture notes](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/intro_analysis_pdf/intro_analysis.html), there is the following theorem and proof on the ratio test for power series:

> **Theorem 10.5.** Suppose that $a_n\neq0$ for all sufficiently large $n$ and the limit $$R=\lim _{n\to \infty }\left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right|\tag1$$ exists or diverges to infinity. Then the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (x-c)^n$ has radius of convergence $R$.

> **Proof.** Let $$r=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}(x-c)^{n+1}}{a_n(x-c)^n}\right|=|x-c|\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right|.\tag2$$ By the ratio test, the power series converges if $0\leq r<1$, or $|x-c|<R$, and diverges if $1<r\leq\infty$, or $|x-c|>R$, which proves the result.

I'm confused about factoring out $|x-c|$ in $(2)$. According to the same lecture notes, this is only possible if $\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right|$ converges. The author has specifically written that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right|$ exists **or** diverges to infinity. This makes me wonder what $\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right|$ converges to in those cases.

To elaborate, consider the case $0<R<\infty$. Then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\left|\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}\right|}=\frac1{R}.$$

Here I've used the rule that if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$ converge, and $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n\neq0$ (which implies that there is some $N$ such that $b_n\neq0$ for $n>N$), then $\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n/b_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n/\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$.

But what about $R=0$ and $R=\infty$? Then what is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right|$? Can we pull out $|x-c|$ nevertheless? Is the statement of the theorem complete as it is or does it lack anything?

Comment: $|x-c|$ is completely independent of the limit variable $n$, if the limit does not exist then it wasn't because of $|x-c|$

Comment: In fact, $c$ is a constant there and _you are keeping $x$ as a constant too_, for the sake of this analysis, and moreover you can assume $x\ne c$ (the power series certainly converges for $x=c$) i.e. $|x-c|>0$, and so the entire thing is about what happens to a converging/diverging sequence when you multiply it by a positive constant. (Hint: it stays what it was previously, converging, or diverging.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $R=\lim _{n\to \infty }\left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right|=0$, then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\left|\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}\right|}=\left[\frac1{0^+}\right]=\infty.$$ To prove this, consider $b_n=\left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right|\geq0$ (since $a_n\neq0$ for sufficiently large $n$, $b_n\neq 0$ for those $n$ too). Now, since $b_n$ converges to $0$, given $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $$n>N\implies b_n<\frac{1}{\epsilon}\wedge b_n\neq 0.$$ For those $n$, $$\frac{1}{b_n}>\epsilon>0>-\epsilon.$$ So for any $M\in \mathbb R$, there exists an $N\in\mathbb N$ such that we can bound $1/b_n$ from below by $M$ whenever $n>N$. One can [show](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3928533/642262) similarly that when $R=\infty$, we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right|=\left[\frac{1}{\infty}\right]=0.$$ Finally, for $C\neq0$, $b_n$ diverges if and only if $Cb_n$ diverges (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2285223/642262) for a proof of this statement).

---

The proof assumes $x\neq c$. When $R=0$, then $r$ diverges to infinity for any $x\neq c$ and so the series converges for no $x\neq c$. When $R=\infty$, then $r=0$ for any $x\neq c$ and thus the series converges for all $x\neq c$. When $x=c$, the series always converges.